Combining two rasters at different resolutions with MapServer as a single WMS layer
I am trying "Join" two rasters with MapServer 7.6.4 so that they appear as a single layer on a WMS service, I have tried the wms_layer_group and GROUP but without luck. |
2 images one high resolution and another low resolution and with different visibility based on scale.
LAYER
    NAME "HighRes"
    TYPE RASTER
    STATUS ON
    EXTENT -64000 100000 -32000 120000
    DATA "/srv/data/orto_high.tif"
    METADATA
      "WMS_LAYER_GROUP" "/test"
    END
    PROJECTION
       "init=epsg:3763"
    END
    MINSCALEDENOM 1000  # Enable this layer at higher zoom levels
  END

  LAYER
    NAME "LowRes"
    TYPE RASTER
    STATUS ON
    EXTENT -64000 100000 -32000 120000
    DATA "/srv/data/orto_low.tif"
    METADATA
      "WMS_LAYER_GROUP" "/test"
    END
    
    PROJECTION
      "init=epsg:3763"
    END
    MAXSCALEDENOM 1000  # Enable this layer at lower zoom levels
  END
END

But no luck my GetCapabilities document as it  is very clearly shows 2 nested layers and I don't want nested layer just a single 1 layer (test). Maybe this is the expected behaviour ?!
<Layer>
<Name>test</Name>
<Title>test</Title>
      <Layer queryable="0" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
      <Name>HighRes</Name>
      :
      <BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:3763" minx="-64000" miny="100000" maxx="-32000" maxy="120000"/>
      :
    </Layer>
    <Layer queryable="0" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
    <Name>LowHigh</Name>
    :
    <BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:3763" minx="-64000" miny="100000" maxx="-32000" maxy="120000"/>
    :
    </Layer>

This looks like a bug on MapServer or maybe this is the expected behavior in a WMS service!?

I think I have used GROUP instead of wms_layer_group LAYER - GROUP "test" - NAME "HighRes" but I do not remember if it hides the layer names or not.

Thank you, I have also tried LAYER - GROUP "test" - NAME "HighRes" but no luck

I think that it should be possible to show only the group layer in GetCapabilities but right I do not have a MapServer to test with. This GeoServer document explains well the layer group behavior in WMS https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/data/webadmin/layergroups.html. Read about the modes. It does not hurt to read the WMS standard as well.

I think I've used all grouping combinations previously whilst looking how best to display data split by country/regions.   You might look at https://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/terrafirma/grouping.html and determine if any fit your needs and will dig out the config.  All services act on the same data

After some testing with MapServer 8.2.0dev I think that it is essential to use an undocumented trick and leave out the LAYER - NAME from the mapfile.
In the LAYER-METADATA define the wms_layer_group and wms_title for each layer
METADATA
        "wms_layer_group" "/test/testgroup_wms"
        "wms_title"           "layer_1"
...

METADATA
        "wms_layer_group" "/test/testgroup_wms"
        "wms_title"           "layer_2"

At the LAYER level, omit NAME totally for the member layers
LAYER
       #NAME ""

...
I left NAME as commented out for making it easier to test and confirm that an empty name NAME "" does not give a desired result.
Now the GetCapabilities response shows
<Layer queryable="1">
<Name>test</Name>
<Title>test</Title>
<Layer queryable="1">
<Name>testgroup_wms</Name>
<Title>testgroup_wms</Title>
<Layer queryable="1" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
<Title>layer_1</Title>
...
</Layer>
<Layer queryable="0" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
<Title>layer_2</Title>
...
</Layer>

Notice that layer_1 and layer_2 have only titles but no names, and in WMS a layer must have a name or it cannot be added to the map.
The sub-layers are totally hidded from the QGIS WMS connection

OpenJUMP does show the titles of the sub-layers but they cannot be selected. Only the group layer "testgroup_wms" that has a name can be selected.

